# What does NSMakeRange(i, 1) mean?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just start to learn iOS.
What does "`NSMakeRange(i, 1)`" mean?

```
for (int i = 0; i < [name length]; i++)
{
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
    NSString *subString = [name substringWithRange:range];
    const char *cString = [subString UTF8String];
    if (strlen(cString) != 3)
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Where is it used?

Comment: UTF-8 can use several bytes to represent a code point, so I suppose the function returns `YES` for some exotic characters. Or doesn’t this work for some reason?

Comment: Seems like _3-char_ characters start at `U+0800`: see [UTF-8 encoding table and Unicode characters](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=2048&number=512)

Comment: @Blender this page is now the top Google result for "NSMakeRange"

Comment: @aednichols: The official documentation is like one result down: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakeRange

Comment: What the code is supposed to do, and whether or not the answer is Googleable, are irrelevant and unkind. Answer the question instead of making side remarks at the OP. Like this: "NSMakeRange(i, 1) creates a range object specifying the characters starting at index i, length=1. In other words, it denotes the ith character of the string. (instead of a char, making a one-character string)"

Answer (score 12):

`NSMakeRange(i, 1)` creates a range with location `i` and length `1`. See the documentation for [NSMakeRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSMakeRange) and [NSString substringWithRange](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange:) for further information and related functions.

Comment: @bdash Broken link to doc. Better to summarize relevant portions of doc in your answer than depend on links that can rot.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-click the function name in Xcode, you’ll get a reference. The function creates a range that starts at `i` and has length of 1. In essence, you’re picking individual characters from the string.

Comment: OK,I will have a try.Thank you!